# Nested cross-validation: How does cross_validate handle GridSearchCV as its input estimator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nested, cross-validation

The following code combines `cross_validate` with `GridSearchCV` to perform a nested cross-validation for an SVC on the iris dataset.

(Modified example of the following documentation page:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-nested-cross-validation-iris-py.)

---

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_validate, KFold
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Load the dataset
iris = load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target

# Set up possible values of parameters to optimize over
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10],
          "gamma": [.01, .1]}

# We will use a Support Vector Classifier with "rbf" kernel
svm = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# Choose techniques for the inner and outer loop of nested cross-validation
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

# Perform nested cross-validation
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv, iid=False)
clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
best_estimator = clf.best_estimator_

cv_dic = cross_validate(clf, X_iris, y_iris, cv=outer_cv, scoring=['accuracy'], return_estimator=False, return_train_score=True)
mean_val_score = cv_dic['test_accuracy'].mean()

print('nested_train_scores: ', cv_dic['train_accuracy'])
print('nested_val_scores:   ', cv_dic['test_accuracy'])
print('mean score:            {0:.2f}'.format(mean_val_score))
```

`cross_validate` splits the data set in each fold into a **training** and a test set. In each fold, the input estimator is then trained based on the training set associated with the fold. The inputted estimator here is `clf`, a parameterized `GridSearchCV` estimator, i.e. an estimator that cross-validates itself again.

I have three questions about the whole thing:

1. If `clf` is used as the estimator for `cross_validate`, does it (in the course of the `GridSearchCV` cross validation) split the above mentioned **training set** into a subtraining set and a validation set in order to determine the best hyper parameter combination?
2. Out of all models tested via `GridSearchCV`, does `cross_validate` validate only the model stored in the `best_estimator_` attribute?
3. Does `cross_validate` train a model at all (if so, why?) or is the model stored in `best_estimator_` validated directly via the test set?

To make it clearer how the questions are meant, here is an illustration of how I imagine the double cross validation at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If `clf` is used as the estimator for `cross_validate`, does it split the above mentioned training set into a subtraining set and a validation set in order to determine the best hyper parameter combination?

Yes as you can see [here at Line 230](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L230) the training set is again split into a subtraining and validation set (Specifically at [line 240](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L240)).

**Update** Yes, when you will pass the `GridSearchCV` classifier into `cross-validate` it will again split the training set into a test and train set. Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230764/8160718) describing this in more detail. Your diagram and assumption is correct.

> Out of all models tested via GridSearchCV, does cross_validate train & validate only the model stored in the variable best_estimator?

Yes, as you can see from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49457445/8160718) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/21888/38068), the GridSearchCV returns the best_estimator in your case(since `refit` parameter is `True` by default in your case.) <s>However, this best estimator will has to be trained again</s>

> Does cross_validate train a model at all (if so, why?) or is the model stored in best_estimator_ validated directly via the test set?

As per your third and final question, Yes, it trains an estimator and returns it if `return_estimator` is set to `True`. See [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L257). Which makes sense, since how else is it supposed to return the scores without training an estimator in the first place ?

**Update** 
The reason the model is trained again is because the default use case for cross-validate does not assume that you give in the best classfier with the optimum parameters. In this case specifically, you are sending in a classifier from the `GridSearchCV` but if you send any untrained classifier it is supposed to be trained. What I mean to say here is that, yes, in your case it shouldn't train it again since you are already doing cross-validation using `GridSearchCV` and using the best estimator. However, there is no way for `cross-validate` to know this, hence, it assumes that you are sending in an un-optimized or rather untrained estimator, thus it has to train it again and return the scores for the same.